# iframe data is not printed properly

Tags: javascript

i am trying to print div data using iframe and div contain grid with pagination when i print div using js only couple of records are printed in .xps file.. why it so...

here is the iframe :

```
<iframe id='ifrmPr' src='#'style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block;border:none;ackground:transparent">    
</iframe>
```

here is my js code to print div

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrmPr');
        var content = document.getElementById('PrintSection').innerHTML;

        /* Determine what DOM model to use */
        var printDoc = (ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument);
        if (printDoc.document) {
            printDoc = printDoc.document;
        }

        /* Create a HTML document to go into the iFrame */
        /* The title will appear on the printed document */
        printDoc.write("<html><head><title>title</title>");
        printDoc.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../Content/pageElement.css' />");
        printDoc.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../Content/Site.css'  />");
        printDoc.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../Content/style.css'  />");
        printDoc.write("</head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
        printDoc.write(content + "</body></html>");
        printDoc.close();
```

Comment: What *is* in the printout? Anything?

Comment: some data is missing in .xps file.

Answer (score 0):

[try this method](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7rp/) instead of using `.write()`

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrmPr');

var printDoc = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument;
if (printDoc.document) {
    printDoc = printDoc.document;
}

var frameBody = printDoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

frameBody.innerHTML = "test";
```

and i think (not sure though), `this` is the window/document object. i think you can call `printDoc.print()` from the parent frame instead of doing it in the child frame.